# Are there extensions which delete cookies the moment you leave a site?

Tags: php, apache, session-cookies

I'm building an ecommerce website, and have had a problem with two different payment gateways. Visitors enter their card details and then leave to the 3D Secure step, which requires visiting their bank's website. When they return from that, they have no cookies on our website, and we cannot recognize them to link up the order.

With one payment gateway, this results in the order failing; with the other, the payment comes through, but is not linked to any specific account or products purchased. Clearly, both of these are problems.

I know that plenty of browsers clear cookies *on closing the browser*, but I'm not aware of any that clear cookies just because you've left the site for a moment. (Furthermore, on one of the two payment gateways, the 3D Secure step is done in an iframe, so the user hasn't even left the site.) It's the user's session which is disappearing.

Concrete questions:

1. Is it common for session cookies to be this volatile? This is behaviour I've been unable to replicate myself. Is there some common browser setting or addon which aggressively (and prematurely) deletes session cookies?
2. Might there be something else causing the effects I'm seeing?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of if we're talking about "standard" redirects (i.e., no curls and whatnot). Are you sure you're not, for example, redirecting to payment gateway from `http://www.example.org` and getting the redirect callback to `http://example.org`? Moreover, most payment gateways, in their payment status notifications, include some sort of information (order id, whatever) that allows you to correlate one such event to a user.

Comment: There _are_ browser extensions like that, the one I am using is https://github.com/Cookie-AutoDelete/Cookie-AutoDelete (and I am very happy with it, because it allows me to just go “yeah, whatever” to all the GDPR cookie popups) … but I don’t think it is very likely that that’s the cause of your issue here. It is probably related to the `SameSite` setting of your session cookie, so check on that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite

Comment: Hmm. A browser setting which automatically upgrades the `SameSite` setting from "Lax" to "Strict" could well cause the issues I'm seeing. That may well be it, @CBroe.

Comment: @CBroe. Setting the session `SameSite` setting to "Strict" did indeed allow me to reproduce the problem (and then provide a workaround), so that's it. Do you want to write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Might there be something else causing the effects I'm seeing?

In this kind of scenario, these days it often has to do with the `SameSite` attribute of the session cookie.

The `Strict` value will prevent cookies from being send in any requests initiated by third party websites. When users are getting redirected back to your site from the payment gateway, that is “navigation” from a 3rd-party site then, and the cookies get not send; so your own session can not be picked up at that point.